# Can PyDev Predefined definitions be case-insensitive?

Tags: python, eclipse-rcp, pydev

I'm using PyDev predefined completions, and I'd like the defined methods to be case-insensitive. Even though python method names are case-sensitive, the predefs I'm implementing represent wrapper methods which delegate to a library which is not case-sensitive. So I'd like for developers to be able to enter lowercase or uppercase method names and both be recognized as valid.

I tried adding duplicate method definitions to the predef file—one in upper case and the other in lower case—but that's apparently not allowed, as it results in neither lower case nor uppercase method names being recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding one entry for the upper case and another for the lower case **should** work, so, if that's not working for you, please report this as a bug in https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev

Comment: Thanks, Fabio. The problem was in my code. I was programmatically generating the pypredef file with hundreds of methods and failed to notice that a few of the methods I was adding are python reserved words when converted to lower case. I detect and skip those now, and it works properly.